# A white gap between two div elements

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML code (the white gap started appearing as soon as I added h3 to the last div):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-image: url("../images/rooms.jpg");
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #343434;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 60px;
  padding-top: 19px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.welcome {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: #406295;
}

.welcome h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">

    <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Room Types</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="welcome">
  <h3>Welcome to</h3>
</div>
```

I am fairly new to web development and stackoverflow. So I am sorry for any inconveniences. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: did you check is there any padding or margin , can you add a snippet or fiddle ?

Comment: try reset css at first. like ` * { padding: 0; margin:0;}

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin: 0px;` on `h3` tag to resolve this issue. Check updated Snippet below..

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-image: url("../images/rooms.jpg");
}

.container{
  width: 80%;
  margin : 0 auto;
}
header{
  background: #343434;
}
header::after{
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear:both;
}

.logo{
  float: left;
  padding:10px;
}
nav{
  float:right;
}
nav ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav li{
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 60px;
  padding-top: 19px;
  position: relative;
}
nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1em 0.5em;

}
nav a:hover{
  color:yellow;
}

.welcome{
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: #406295;
}

.welcome h3{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
 <header>
    <div class="container">

      <a href="#" class = "logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Room Types</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="welcome">
    <h3>Welcome to</h3>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.

Comment: @ArnoldHeinminthant If my answer solved your problem then please accept it..

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `style="display: inline; margin:0px; padding:0px;"` to your `<h3>` Tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `margin` from h3 like

```
.welcome h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-image: url("../images/rooms.jpg");
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #343434;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 60px;
  padding-top: 19px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.welcome {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: #406295;
}

.welcome h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">

    <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Room Types</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="welcome">
  <h3>Welcome to</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [collapsing margins](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/)

Remove the `margin` on the `h3`. Replace it with `padding` if you want to create space between the header and maintain the background colour.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-image: url("../images/rooms.jpg");
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #343434;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 60px;
  padding-top: 19px;
  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.welcome {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background: #406295;
}

.welcome h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">

    <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Room Types</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="welcome">
  <h3>Welcome to</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either apply `margin-top:0` for `H3`-Tag
or
apply a `float:left` for .welcome

Both will fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to apply a rule of `overflow: auto` to the `.welcome` div... thus creating a new block formatting context and avoiding the collapsing margins.

Edit: Let's add a little more context. In [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-model), you can read that adjoining margins will collapse under certain circumstances. In particular, the margins need to belong to block-level boxes participating in the same block formatting context.

Even though `.welcome` and `h3` are block-level boxes in your example, neither automatically establishes a new block formatting context (meaning they participate in the same block formatting context, meaning their margins collapse). Looking at [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) again, we see that some of the ways to establish a new block formatting context is to have a float, an absolutely positioned element, or a block box with the property of `overflow` set to something else than `visible`.

That's why the suggestions regarding `overflow: auto` or floating one of the elements work. My understanding is that if we make `.welcome` establish a new block formatting context, the context it participates in is different from the one it establishes itself. Removing the margin (possibly replacing it with padding) is another way to get around the problem.